# Foreach with async c#

Tags: c#, .net-core

Im calling async method like this:

```
foreach (var item in someList)
{
    item.someValue = asdf.Where(() => SomeMethod(item)).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

How do I get it to work asynchronously? I want to await all results. I'm using .Net Core 3.1

Comment: Check out Task.WaitAll

Comment: Is the `.Where(()=>SomeMethod(item)).FirstOrDefaultAsync()` really pertinent to this example?  Could the same question be asked with any async function for which you are trying to avoid the `await` in the loop such as: `item.somevalue = SomeMethodAsync(item)`?  Which is equally wrong, but conveys the exact same intent, I feel and is simpler / minimal.

Comment: [Stephen Cleary's point](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61764665/1563833) about Entity Framework not supporting multiple concurrent queries on the same context could be highly relevant to your overall success - even if you do figure out the Task.WhenAll thing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For asynchronous concurrency, the best approach is to use `await Task.WhenAll`:

```
var tasks = someList.Select(async item =>
{
  item.someValue = await asdf.Where(() => SomeMethod(item)).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
});
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

However, it looks like you might be using Entity Framework. In that case, you'll need to be aware that Entity Framework *does not support* multiple concurrent queries on the same context. You will either need to run your queries one at a time, or use multiple db contexts.

Comment: I feel like you've raised an important red flag about FirstOrDefaultAsync probably being part of Entity Framework and not supporting multiple concurrent queries on the same context.  If only your text could be bolder and blinkier.  I'll upvote and comment, which is about all I can do to help.

Comment: **<blink>Thanks!</blink>**

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like below

```
var myTasks = someList.Select(async x => 
{
   //Your code here
});
```

Await for all the tasks to complete

```
await Task.WhenAll(myTasks);
```

Comment: Is the `.ToList()` really necessary?  `Task.WhenAll` accepts an IEnumerable, so... I think not.